# equation for logarithm​ to find the value

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve this problem:

> Solve $5^{4x-1}=7^{x+2}$, to 2 decimal places.

Please I need someone to help me with this problem. Thanks

Comment: Let me remind you that I posted the following on your previous question, but it does not seem like you got the message: *"Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, please try to make the title more descriptive, there are a lot of questions about simultaneous equations for logarithms."* Maybe there is something you don't understand about it?

Comment: @projectilemotion I second that.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to substitute the x value and y value to confirm the answer but it is not working well. The final answer are different and that makes me confused with the answers. I am still looking for an answer to that question.

Comment: There are multiple "answers" to this question... that is, they are all the same number, but they look different depending on whether the solver decided to use the natural log, logarithm base $5$, or logarithm base $7$.

Comment: I used logarithm to solve but it than confused me with the answers that I got.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Notice that any number $n$ is equal to
$$n=a^{\log_a n}$$
Therefore we can transform your equation into
$$7^{\log_7 5^{4x-1}}=7^{x+2}$$

Comment: Thanks for your hint, and also for not handing a fully baked answer to the OP.

Comment: And thank you for recognizing that as more appropriate that a fully baked answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

$$5^{4x-1}=7^{x+2}\implies (4x-1)\ln 5=(x+2)\ln7$$

$$\implies x(4\ln 5-\ln 7)=2\ln 7+\ln 5\implies x=\frac{2\ln7+\ln 5}{4\ln 5-\ln 7} \approx 1.22\quad\text{two d.p.}$$

Comment: I will not downvote, because the criteria for downvoting is *"This answer is not useful"*, and your answer is useful, but note that you put yourself at risk since the question in its current state has no context whatsoever, and some users do downvote full answers to those types of questions.

Comment: You shouldn't just answer his question like that... it's like doing his homework for him. Perhaps give him a hint on how to do it instead?

Comment: @Frpzzd You had already provided a good hint, my answer is for if the OP gets stuck, and also for future visitors to the site. By looking at the steps in my answer, one can extrapolate this for other similar problems.

Comment: You should wait for the OP to demonstrate that he has already attempted to solve the problem and has already gotten stuck before you spoon-feed it to him.

Comment: @Frpzzd I don't just answer for the OP, it is for other visitors to the site. Anyways that's all I have to say, down vote if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

This is more Algebra II than Abstract Algebra, but I'll show you the steps. Here, log denotes the natural logarithm.

$5^{4x-1}$ = $7^{x+2}$ 
(4x-1) log(5) =(x+2) log(7) 
4x log(5) - log(5) = xlog(7) + 2 log(7) 
4xlog (5) -xlog(7) = 2log(7) + log(5) 
x [log($5^4$) - log(7)] = log(49 . 5) 
x = $\frac{\log \left(49.5\right)}{\log \left(\frac{5^4}{7}\right)}$

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Generally, when someone asks a question that seems straight out of their homework, you shouldn't answer it for them. It is better to leave a hint.

Comment: You can use "\cdot" to write the multiplication.